# Without use the theorem that state $cr(C_3 \times C_t)=t$ for $t \geq 3$, show that $2 \leq cr(C_3 \times C_3) \leq 3$

Tags: graph-theory

Without use the theorem that state $cr(C_3 \times C_t)=t$ for $t \geq 3$, show that $2 \leq cr(C_3 \times C_3) \leq 3$

Here is what I got

[image]

This is the graph of $C_3\times C_3$. It doen't matter how I draw it, the edge between the vertex of inner triangle and outer triangle only cross an edge of middle triangle one. Since Crossing number is the minimum number of cross in all drawing of $G$ so $cr(C_3 \times C_3)$ can't be more than 3. So $cr(C_3 \times C_3) \leq 3$

For the first part $2 \leq cr(C_3 \times C_3)$. I want to use a theorem that say if $G$ is a graph of order $n \geq 3$ and size $m$ then $cr(G) \geq m-3n+6$. However this graph has $n=9, m=18$ and $m-3n+6=18-27+6= -3$. I'm now sure how to continue from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph without the purple lines is planar. Let's call it $H$.

If you add one purple line, you immediately find a subdivision of $K_5$, so $H+e$ is not planar anymore. But then $H$ is a maximal planar subgraph and $cr(G)\geq |E(G)|-|E(H)|=3$.

Comment: So from my argument I've showed that $cr(G) \leq3$  and yours say it $\geq 3$, so $cr(G)=3$. What I'm confused is they wan to show it's $geq2$ that mean $cr(G)$ can be $2$ or the fact that $cr(G) =3$ already cover that part?

Comment: Yes. It is allowed to derive $2\leq x\leq 3$ from $x=3$. It suggests however that your tutor has a different proof in mind, but since this one does not use the forbidden theorem I do not see any problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have one more question, why $cr(G) = |E(G)|-|E(H)|$? is this a theorem ?

Comment: It is a theorem, but the proof is very simple: if $H$ is a maximal planar subgraph, then every additional edge has to cross at least one line.

Comment: oh, I see it now, Thank you very much.